# Excel VBA: Single Loop + If-Statement; Run-time Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

I want to loop through a column and compare all cells in that range with the value x of the cell "AD2". If the value of the cell i is smaller than the value x, I want cell i to be marked red. While running following code:

```
Sub Button10()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Range("AD2").Value
    If Cells(i, 26).Value < x Then
        Cells(i, 26).Font.Color = vbRed
        For i = 1 To 500
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

I get following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method '_Default' of object 'Range' failed.

Comment: Google `For Loop vba`  Your loop is incorrect.  The for loop should before and the Next after IF not inside the if.

Comment: After the second look, the For-Loop logic is obviously flawed, thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that I've [indented your code](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) hopefully you can see that your logic is outside your `For` loop when it should be inside it.

You get an error because when you declare `i As Long` it is initialised with the value of `0`. Therefore this line will fail because `i = 0` is does not return a valid range:

```
If Cells(i, 26).Value < x Then
```

So try this:

```
Sub Button10()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Range("AD2").Value
    For i = 1 To 500
        If Cells(i, 26).Value < x Then
            Cells(i, 26).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I can see, that the For-Loop logic together with the If-Statement doesn't make sense with my old arrangement. Thank you also for the great vba-intender tool, gonna use it :).